# Problemas con fechas en Excel al pasarlas a RStudio

Tags: excel, date, rstudio

Tengo un dataset con una columna que en excel se muestra como fecha, cuando realizo la importacion de datos a R, el resultado es el siguiente.

```
 base <- read.xlsx("c:/Users/80926501/Desktop/10_PORTAFOLIO Y PROSPECTOS_OCTUBRE_2020.xlsx", 
+                    sheet = "DETALLE COLOCACION", skipEmptyRows = T, startRow = 9)
> str(base$FEC.DESEMBOLSO)

 num [1:57704] 40840 37999 40960 35632 41163 ...
```

Cuando uso el codigo aparentemente queda bien guardada, pero al vereficar en la nueva base, me encuentro con fechas que no corresponden a las reales, a las que estan guardadas en Excel:

```
base$FEC.DESEMBOLSO <-as.Date(base$FEC.DESEMBOLSO)
```

Por favor podrian ayudame.

Gracias.

Comment: Las fechas en Excel son números enteros. Concretamente, 40840 equivale a 24/10/2011, 37999 13/01/2004, etc. ¿Podría ser que te las está reconociendo como números en vez de como fechas? ¿Qué pasa si pones un apóstrofe `'` antes de la fecha, en la misma celda?

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pued mira que me sale lo siguiente; Error in as.Date.numeric(base$FEC.DESEMBOLSO) : 'origin' must be supplied

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir el parámetro `detectDates = TRUE`

```
 base <- read.xlsx("c:/Users/80926501/Desktop/10_PORTAFOLIO Y PROSPECTOS_OCTUBRE_2020.xlsx",
```

- ```
                 sheet = "DETALLE COLOCACION", skipEmptyRows = T, startRow = 9, detectDates = TRUE)
  ```

Prueba a ver si la posición del parámetro es correcta, ya que de R ni idea, lo acabo de googlear.